# Format an Integer using Java String Format

Tags: java, string-formatting, number-formatting

I am wondering if it is possible, using the String.format method in Java, to give an integer preceding zeros?

For example:

1 would become 001
2 would become 002
...
11 would become 011
12 would become 012
...
526 would remain as 526
...etc

At the moment I have tried the following code:

```
String imageName = "_%3d" + "_%s";

for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ ){
    System.out.println( String.format( imageName, i, "foo" ) );
}
```

Unfortunately, this precedes the number with 3 empty spaces. Is it possible to precede the number with zeros instead?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add leading zeroes in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-in-java)

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Use `%03d` in the format specifier for the integer. The `0` means that the number will be zero-filled if it is less than three (in this case) digits.

See the [`Formatter`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) docs for other modifiers.

Answer (score 245):

```java
String.format("%03d", 1)  // => "001"
//              │││   └── print the number one
//              ││└────── ... as a decimal integer
//              │└─────── ... minimum of 3 characters wide
//              └──────── ... pad with zeroes instead of spaces
```

See [`java.util.Formatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) for more information.

Answer (score 13):

If you are using a third party library called apache commons-lang, the following solution can be useful:

Use `StringUtils` class of apache [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) :

```
int i = 5;
StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(i), 3, "0"); // --> "005"
```

As `StringUtils.leftPad()` is faster than `String.format()`

Comment: StringUtils.leftPad is another good choice and could be argued that it is more readable plus it allows you to pad with other characters. I have had a Google around but I cannot find anything that confirms it is faster - could you provide some evidence for that?

Comment: https://github.com/anilbharadia/JavaPerformanceTests/blob/master/PerformanceTests/src/org/rw/performance/StringUtilsVsStringFormat.java Run it with junit and check the time

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using String.format(**). it's good if you use DecimalFormat java API which builds for this type of purposes.Let me explain with code

```
    String pattern = "000";
   double value = 12; //can be 536 or any 
   DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern);
   String formattedNumber = formatter.format(value);
   System.out.println("Number:" + value + ", Pattern:" +
                pattern + ", Formatted Number:" +
                formattedNumber);
```

Comment: Why do you think so?