# Write String with preceding zeros into CSV file in java

Tags: java, string, file

I am trying to write account numbers(e.g: 00000900123) into csv file in java. After creating a file and writing account number gets converted into 900123 automatically. How can i code to make it retain the preceding zeros in the file.

```
public class WriteData {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    String header = "name, accountNumber, amount";
    String record = "savings, 000090123, 12000.0";

    File file = new File("testfile.csv");
    try {

        fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(fileOutputStream));

        bufferedWriter.write(header);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();
        bufferedWriter.write(record);
        bufferedWriter.newLine();

    } catch(FileNotFoundException fne) {
    } catch(IOException ioe) {
    } finally {
        if (bufferedWriter != null) {
            try {
                bufferedWriter.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }

        if (fileOutputStream != null) {
            try {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}

 }
```

After i run the above program it generates a testfile.csv. If i open it in text editor it shows the full string as below,

```
name, accountNumber, amount
savings, 000090123, 12000.0
```

But if i open in csv account number would be 90123. We need to provide the csv file to client so complete account number is required.

Comment: Show us the code and we'll tell you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format an Integer using Java String Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034523/format-an-integer-using-java-string-format)

Comment: Can you identify whether the leading zeroes are stripped at display by the software you're using to read CSVs, or at write-time by your java code? (I suggest you open the .csv file with a text editor to make sure)

Comment: Btw. While "account numbers" are called "numbers" it would probably be best to not treat them as numbers but Strings instead. The "International Bank Account Number" (IBAN) for example actually also contains letters.

Comment: I have added the code above.

Comment: This is not a question that needs to be tied to java it is an Excel or the corresponding tool you are using to open the file. Please add tags accordingly.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am hoping that you are using Excel to open the CSV, I would recommend using excel and following these [instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/keeping-leading-zeros-and-large-numbers-1bf7b935-36e1-4985-842f-5dfa51f85fe7) to get what you need.
Hope this helps, once you have the data imported save the file and share it with the users.