# Android Studio not accepting regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I am making a simple regex to determine integers of length 1-4 from string my regex is:

```
\d{1,4}
```

My Regex is valid in all online regex testing sites such as [regex101](https://regex101.com/) but Android studio is not accepting this Regex
[please find image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgshX.png).

I need your  help in finding any silly mistakes in this.
Sample:

```
Regex: \d{1,4}
String: dgsdfg700
Match: 700
```

Please tell where am I doing wrong so studio is not accepting my regex and all other sites are.

MY code:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{1,4}");

            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mystring);
            if (matcher.find())
            {
             //my stuff here
            }
```

Comment: What you have done so far ? Show some code.

Comment: Are you using it in `.matches()`? `\d{1,4}` is a valid pattern to find 1 to 4 digit chunks in a string when you use `.find()`.

Comment: Show us a bit more code please - your test string and output because what you have should work?

Comment: @Elemental  Please see the image in the link

Comment: @Aj27 Please look now

Comment: input `700` instead of `dgsdfg700`, still red?

Comment: use this link : [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034523/format-an-integer-using-java-string-format#autocomment84323933)

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isValid(final String pass){
        Pattern pattern;
        Matcher matcher;
        final String PASS_PATTERN = "^[0-9]{1,4}$";
        pattern = Pattern.compile(PASS_PATTERN);
        matcher = pattern.matcher(pass);

        return matcher.matches();
    }
```

Comment: If the answer is correct or helpful, Please let me know in the comment box.