# I want to create unique user id

Tags: java, android-studio

I just create unique id but with random number. but I want to create that id like jason-001,smith-002,etc.

```
Integer user_id= new Random().nextInt();

//implementation
reference_uploaded_by.getRef().setValue(name.getText().toString() + "-" + user_id);
```

Comment: *unique* and *random*. Are you sure?

Comment: If this ID is for _identification_, why not use a UUID? like `id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();`

Comment: Poor title. Rewrite to be specific to your technical issue.

Comment: Are you asking how to best to create a unique user id? Or are you asking specifically how to create a string consisting of name plus a sequence number? Work to make your Question narrowly-focused and very specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`AtomicLong#incrementAndGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet--) as a counter. The “Atomic” means the class is [thread-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety).

```
AtomicLong userIdIncrementor = new AtomicLong(previouslyUsedNumber);
```

Use that object to get incrementing numbers for each new user.

```
long number = userIdIncrementor.incrementAndGet();
String userId = userName + String.format("%03d", number);
```

This code assumes you will never have more than a thousand users, with only three digits for the number as you specified in your Question.

For details on formatting an integer, see [this Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034579/642706).