How to get the code to display scanner input numbers as output?
In Java, I'm trying to learn and I am at a bit of a loss. My class wants me to:

Create a program that can be used to add two integers together. In the beginning, the user is asked to give two integers that are to be summed. The program then prints the formula that describes the addition of the numbers.

I'm stuck with trying to get it to describe the addition of the numbers.
So far I've gotten this far:
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdditionFormula {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Give the first number: ");
        int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Give the second number: ");
        int second = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        System.out.println();

    }
}

And I'm stuck with the last line there, trying to figure out how to get it to display what I've already had scanned. I am capable of making it add the numbers together, but I'm not sure how to get it to display those input numbers as well. Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6034579/22851022

That doesn't really answer my question, but thank you for the link. I'll add that to my studying.

Hello ellebelle1512, welcome, you can use: System.out.println( "The sum of " + first + " and " + second + " is: " + ( first + second ));.

This question is similar to: Java printing a String containing an integer. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can use either of the below ways to achieve it.
Approach 1 : adding the numbers and storing them in a new variable and then printing it in two different steps .
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AdditionFormula {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give the first number: ");
    int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Give the second number: ");
    int second = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    
    int sum = first + second;
    System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = " + sum);

}

}
Approach 2: Adding and printing the numbers in a single step .
import java.util.Scanner;
public class AdditionFormula {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Give the first number: ");
    int first = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    System.out.println("Give the second number: ");
    int second = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
    
    // Calculate and print the sum in one line
    System.out.println(first + " + " + second + " = " + (first + second));

}

}

At the last you should create a sum variable and make it to add both the number like this =
int sum = First + Second
System.out.print(sum);
This should help  you out
