# In java, I want to do 102%100 and get the remainder as 02 and not as 2.. How do i do that?

Tags: java, modulus

In java, I want to do 102%100 and get the remainder as 02 and not as 2.. How do i do that?

int a = (102%100);

a returns 2 and not 02.. I want to get 02..
because originally, it's supposed to be 1.02, but mod returns 2. :(
Anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You're confusing numbers with String representation of numbers -- a subtle but important difference.

Answer (score 5):

`2` and `02` are the same number.

Since you are using this to find the first two numbers after the decimal-point, just pad any one-digit numbers with a `0`.  If you want all the numbers after the decimal-point, the more usual way is to do this:

```
//Strip all numbers before decimal-point
double decimalDigits = myNumber - (int)myNumber;
```

Comment: is there no automatic way to do that? T_T

Comment: @황현정: If you are only doing this for ease of display, then yes, there is; in fact, you can automatically format decimals without all this hoopla.  Check out the [string formatter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) classes.

Answer (score 3):

[NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) is probably the best way to go. String.format and doing calculations also work, but since you're formatting a number, might as well use a number formatter.

An example. I'm guessing on your requirements here a bit (e.g. what should 110%100 return, or do you only expect a single-digit remainder?):

```
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("'0'#");
int remainder = 102%100;
System.out.println(formatter.format(remainder));
```

Answer (score 1):

As integers, they represent the same number. Use the following to format the number as a string for display purposes:

```
int a = 102 / 100;
int r = 102 % 100;
System.out.print(a + "." + String.format("%02d", r));
```

Output:

```
1.02
```

Answer (score 0):

Here lies the answer to padding numbers with zeroes: [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-in-java)

Really though, thats it.