# Display numbers with leading zeros (0) in Java?

Tags: java, int

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Say that I have to add two integers one being 0001 and the other 0002. If I add it in java then I get 3 however I would like 0003. Would I have to make a loop to map out the zeros or is there an easier way.

Comment: How do you add the integers `0001` and `0002`?

Comment: Yep, what Hovercraft says -- you have two integers 1 and 2.  The fact that they may be represented as 0001 and 0002 in some contexts has nothing to do with their actual values.

Comment: Be careful! `0001` and `0002` are interpreted in Java as octal numbers since it starts with `0`, so `010` is actually `8` not `10`.

Answer (score 14):

Don't confuse numbers with String representation of numbers. Your question revolves around the latter -- how to represent a number as a String with leading zeros, and there are several possible solutions including using a DecimalFormat object or String.format(...).

i.e.,

```
  int myInt = 5;
  String myStringRepOfInt = String.format("%05d", myInt);
  System.out.println("Using String.format: " + myStringRepOfInt);

  DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("00000");
  System.out.println("Using DecimalFormat: " + decimalFormat.format(myInt));
```

Comment: But how would I add them

Comment: @Tom: Please clarify -- add what? You need to show your code and more information on exactly where your stuck to make your question answerable.

Answer (score 8):

you can add a left pad with zeros after having the result.

```
String.format("%05d", result);
```

for zero-padding with length=5.

**EDIT**: i to removed the previous  EDIT, it was totally wrong :@

Comment: Your edit is completely wrong, and in fact your code in your original answer solves the problem that your edit messes up. Please run a small program to show to yourself that this is so.  Sorry, but I must give you a -1 vote until you fix this error.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

String.format (http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

In your case it will be: String.format("%03d", num) - 0 - to pad with zeros, 3 - to set width to 3