# Represent String `000000001` to Integer `000000001`

Tags: java

```
String s = 000000001;
String e = 009999999;
```

Convert String `000000001` to Integer `000000001`.

I tried doing this with Integer.parseInt

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
```

I am getting n = 1, but I want n should have 000000001

```
for (int ind = Integer.valueOf(s); ind < Integer.valueOf(e); ind++)  {

  String pp = "ggg" + ind; // I want pp should be like this- ggg000000001 and it keep on increasing like   ggg000000002, then ggg000000003 and etc etc.   
}
```

Comment: What would all those leading zeros mean in an `Integer`? Do you want to _format the output_ differently?

Comment: That doesn't make sense; leading zeros don't exist in an integer, they only exist in a string.  I assume you are asking "how do I format the output when I display an integer?".

Comment: The integer 000000001 does not exist

Comment: `String s = 009999999;` Err... what? Did you try to compile that? You probably want some quotes there.

Comment: If you were to convert the String `000000001` into an integer somehow, it would be considered to be an **octal** number (with leading zeros).

Comment: All :  this is a valid question - in some countries numbers may be shown this way. Also, sometimes data has to be standardized. `001, 012, 123` looks better than `1, 12, 123`

Comment: The integer "1" *is* the integer "00000001".  If you want to *represent* "1" as "0000001", then look at Bohemian's "format()" example.

Comment: @Adel: The underlying problem is valid, but the way the question is phrased doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The integer `000000001` *is* `1`. I can only assume you want to *display* `1` as `000000001`. This is how you do it:

```
System.out.format("%09d", n);
```

Here's a little test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "000000001";
    int n = Integer.parseInt(s);
    System.out.format("%09d", n);
}
```

Output:

```
000000001
```

FYI [`System.out.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) is a convenience facade for `System.out.println(String.format())`, so if you need the String in your code (and don't want to output it) use:

```
String s = String.format("%09d", n);
```

#### Updated due to question update:

```
String pp = String.format("ggg%09d", ind);
```

Comment: I have updated my question what I actual want. I want String pp should keep on increasing with the ID value.

Comment: OK - I've added an update to address your (new) need

Answer (score 1):

You may use the class [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) to [do this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html):

```
DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat(pattern); 
String output= myFormatter.format(value); 
System.out.println(value + " " + pattern + " " + output);
```

See this question too: [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)