# Increment Int Number

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

For my program I have to make this types of code

i.e `ABC000001`, `ABC000002`  and so on,

First three characters are fixed and after that code should incremented,

code like :

```
int i = 000001;
String str = "ABC";

loop{
    String temp = str + i;
    i = i + 1;
}
```

when I used `int` 000001 consider as 1.

if 10 code will show like `ABC000010` 
and if code will 100 then `ABC000100`, `ABC000101`
And So on...

So Any one can tell me what should I have to do to getting this type of Result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a trivial job for [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) (since J2SE 5.0)

```
String temp = String.format("ABC%06d", i);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the number using one of the `java.text` utilities, otherwise the number will be a "1", not a "000001".