# Format string to a 3 digit number

Tags: c#, string, numbers, format

Instead of doing this, I want to make use of `string.format()` to accomplish the same result:

```
if (myString.Length < 3)
{
    myString =  "00" + 3;
}
```

Comment: Let's have a look at this post : [here in stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Comment: Can you clarify why `myString` should become "003"?  What is the correlation with the number '3' aside from the intended length?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

If you're just formatting a number, you can just provide the proper [custom numeric format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx) to make it a 3 digit string directly:

```
myString = 3.ToString("000");
```

Or, alternatively, use the [standard D format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
myString = 3.ToString("D3");
```

Comment: If you want to use the formatted number directly in a constructed string, you can also use:

`string.Format("This is my number: {0:D3}", number)`

Comment: @coeing realize that this will only work when `number` is an int. If `number` is a double, for instance, it will have to be `string.Format("{0:000}", number)`

Comment: Or string interpolation `$"This is my number: {number.ToString("D3")}";`

Comment: Shorter string interpolation `var myString = $"This is my number: {number:D3}";`

Answer (score 35):

```
 string.Format("{0:000}", myString);
```

Answer (score 23):

This is how it's done using string interpolation C# 7

```
$"{myString:000}"
```

Answer (score 20):

It's called [Padding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66f6d830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
myString.PadLeft(3, '0')
```

Comment: thats the brute force method, not as the question asked with the format option

Comment: Is there a scenario where that would yield a different result?  Technically `.ToString()` isn't directly using `String.Format()` either (although it will under the hood)...

Comment: `.ToString("format")` and `String.Format("format", value)` is the same: formatting a value with a format string.

Comment: It isn't clear from the question that the formatting should always be applied to a static number (why the OP chose to use '3' is still unclear to me, hence my question above).  It may well be some other characters and can't use the numeric formatters.  Padding is a safe alternative in such a case.

Answer (score 10):

This is a short hand string [format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) [Interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/strings/):

```
$"{value:D3}"
```

Answer (score 9):

*(Can't comment yet with enough reputation , let me add a sidenote)*

Just in case your output need to be fixed length of 3-digit , i.e. for number run up to 1000 or more (reserved fixed length), don't forget to add  **mod 1000** on it .

```
yourNumber=1001;
yourString= yourNumber.ToString("D3");        // "1001" 
yourString= (yourNumber%1000).ToString("D3"); // "001" truncated to 3-digit as expected
```

Trail sample on Fiddler https://dotnetfiddle.net/qLrePt

Comment: This introduces an extra, unnecessary step.

Comment: @Paul - He is saying that IF the input might be > 1000, and the requirement is that the output always be EXACTLY 3 characters, then one way to meet that requirement is to force the incoming number to fit within 3 digits; e.g. MOD.  As the comments on his code lines show, just using "D3" will output 4 characters for the value 1001. So instead, for this usage scenario, use the final line. (For example, I have used a similar technique in debugging output, when the value is part of a complex object that I am printing details of, and I want details to line up, ok to miss some high digits.)

Answer (score 3):

"How to: Pad a Number with Leading Zeros"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be `String.Format`?

This looks like a job for `String.Padleft`

```
myString=myString.PadLeft(3, '0');
```

Or, if you are converting direct from an int:

```
myInt.toString("D3");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
string.Format("{0:D3}, 3);
```