# c# - How can i format a string in c#

Tags: c#

I have a very simple  Question to ask.

I have a string like:

```
         string str="89";
```

I want to format my string as follow :

```
         str="000089";
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Is the format always going to be 4 0's?

Comment: use string.Format() ?

Comment: `str="000089";` seems to do what you want... in the real code, is the 89 actually coming from another variable?

Comment: no at all,as the number incerase the zero's from left replaced by the numbers.. like "000130" and "001457"

Comment: yes @MarcGravell...

Comment: I think you have nice answers below, but your question sounds like a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12570807/format-string-to-a-3-digit-number

Comment: Uuuugh! So sick of seeing high rep users answering poor questions that will very obviously have a dupe target.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming the 89 is actually coming from another variable, then simply:

```
    int i = 89;
    var str = i.ToString("000000");
```

Here the `0` in the `ToString()` is a "zero placeholder" as a custom format specifier; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

Answer (score 6):

If you have a `string` (not `int`) as the initial value and thus you want to *pad* it up to length `6`, try `PadLeft`:

```
   string str = "89";

   str = str.PadLeft(6, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the input to be a string you'll have to parse it before you output it

```
int.Parse(str).ToString("000000")
```

Comment: In *that* scenario (where `str` has the value), I suspect `str = str.PadLeft(6, '0');` would be more efficient

Comment: @MarcGravell I think so too