# Java Random Print

Tags: java, random, numbers

I generate a random number between 0-99 using this :

```
int num2= (int)(Math.random() * ((99) + 1));
```

When the number is below 10 I want it to print with a 0num2
So if the number is 9 it would be 09.

How can I get it to print this?

Comment: Why not use * 100 directly? Why 99 + 1?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/275716/779982

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) method:

```
System.out.format("%02d%n", num2);
```

`%02d` prints the argument as a number with width 2, padded with 0's
`%n` gives you a newline

Answer (score 3):

```
System.out.println((num2 < 10 ? "0" : "") + num2);
```

One liner :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
String str;
if (num2 < 10) str = "0" + num2;
else str = "" + num2;

System.out.println("Value is: " + str);
```

Comment: Where's an easy button when you need one?

Comment: Haha, to enjoy the pleasure of pushing it and hearing the phrase "That was easy".

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [`PrintStream.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), which will allow you to print using specified widths and padding characters.

`System.out` is a `PrintStream`, so you can use `System.out.format` in place of `println`.

Your case is pretty simple, look over the [syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) for the format string:

```
System.out.format("%02d", num2);
```

Here *2* is the minimum width, and the *0* specifies that the result be padded with zeros, if the width of the result is less than 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the approach of removing an extra digit instead.

```
System.out.println(("" + (int)(Math.random()*100 + 100)).substring(1));
```

or to use the String format.

```
String s = String.format("%02d", (int)(Math.random()*100));
```

or

```
System.out.printf("%02d", (int)(Math.random()*100));
```

I would generally use the last option as it allows you to combine other strings and print them.

Comment: Do you think that would be better than appending an extra 0 if needed? If so, why? Also, you're getting a number from 100 to 199, not 0 to 99. But I hope you knew that.

Comment: After removing the first digit 100 to 199 becomes 00 to 99.  As to whether its better is a matter of taste.

Comment: It makes the code both harder to read and, most likely, slower (even though a very tiny bit)... Don't see any point at all in using substring to do the job.