# Add prefix to number e.g (1 = 001)

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

I want to add prefix to my number. I have number which i want to convert it in 3 digits e.g
if i pass 1 than it should return 001. Here is my code.

```
public int returnThreeDigitNo(int number)
{
    int threeDigitNo = 0;
    int length = String.valueOf(number).length();
    if(length == 1)
    {
        threeDigitNo = 00+number;
    }
    if(length == 2)
    {
        threeDigitNo = 0+number;
    }
    if(length == 3)
    {
        threeDigitNo = number;
    }
    return threeDigitNo;
}
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you want to display an int with 3 digits you can use:

```
String.format("%03d", yournumber);
```

Comment: Worked like a mass..

Comment: I tried in scala and got a long and unusual error message, in Scala your String format code will now look like this: `val res = "%03d".format(yournumber)
`

Comment: is there a way to do this in javascript?