# How to save animation as a file (“Algorithms 4th Edition” by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.)

Tags: java, animation, save

I am reading "Algorithms 4th Edition" by Robert Sedgewick and Kevin Wayne.
Using `StdDraw`, we can create animation:

```
package general_test;

import edu.princeton.cs.algs4.StdDraw;

public class AnimationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       StdDraw.setScale(-2, +2);
       StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();

       for (double t = 0.0; true; t += 0.02) {
           double x = Math.sin(t);
           double y = Math.cos(t);
           StdDraw.clear();
           StdDraw.filledCircle(x, y, 0.05);
           StdDraw.filledCircle(-x, -y, 0.05);
           StdDraw.show();
           StdDraw.pause(20);
       }
    }

}
```

I want to save this animation as a file.
How can I save this animation as a file?
Any easy way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Very easy way**

1. Add counter.

```java
int counter = 0;
```

2. Limit the number of iteration steps to let's say 1000.

```java
for (double t = 0.0; t < 20; t += 0.02)
```

3. Save every iteration step as an PNG file.

```java
StdDraw.save("image-"+String.format("%03d", counter++)+".png");
```

4. Use ffmpeg to convert these files to a video file.

```java
ffmpeg -i image-%03d.png video.webm
```

Enjoy!

**References**

- https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/image_sequence
- [Add prefix to number e.g (1 = 001)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745297/add-prefix-to-number-e-g-1-001/12745320)

Comment: Wojciech Domalewski, Thank you very much for your answer!