# Zero padding to a given width

Tags: java, formatting

How can I write a method with this header

```
public static String format (int number, int width)
```

that would return a string for the number with one or more prefix 0s. the size of the string is the width?  example if use use `format(43, 4)` the output is `0043`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Comment: "Not a real question" seems problematic.  There is enough there to go on, though ideally it would explain what was tried.

Comment: The question is good, the attitude not really. The answer you will find in this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Comment: this sounds like homework to me

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public static String format(int number, int width) {
    return String.format("%0" + width + "d", number);
}
```

Comment: Because you used string concatenation in for, You do not use the language API that have solved this type of problem years ago.