# Formating an integer with %h while adding leading zeros

Tags: java, format

I am trying to format an integer with `h` format specifier while adding leading zeros to it, if it is less then 4 digits. As

```
//crac is int with some value
String formated=String.format("%04h ", carc);//works fine if I use d instead of h but I want h
```

It gives the follwoing exception

```
java.util.FormatFlagsConversionMismatchException: Conversion = h, Flags = 0
```

but it not gives the exception while I remove leading zero, as

```
String formated=String.format("%4h ", carc);
```

How I can fix that? While I want to add leading zeros. See [Add leading zeros to number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)
 I want to use begray's solution, it looks prefect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the 0 flag with the h format specifier, for no reason whatsoever. I would file a bug report. If you want to really do this, you can use:

```
String formatted = String.format("%04d", obj.hashCode());
```

Comment: Wait a minute, do you even know what %h does? It outputs the hashCode of the parameter.

Comment: but it is giving me value in decimal, I want in Hex at one step so that did not worked, but the following worked `formatted=String.format("%04x", ((Object)carc).hashCode()))`. I know what I am doing. But how I can do that neatly as above has a casting and a function call?

Comment: First, the cast to `Object` is useless and can be eliminated. You still need the function call.