# Get a 01 from an int instead of 1 in a for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, formatting, integer

This loop inserts employee Ids like 1, 2, 4,.. 30.

```
for(int i=01;i<31;i++){
  Employee e = new Employee();
  e.setEmpId(i);
  aList.add(e);
}
```

However, I require the ids in the format 01, 02, 03 .. so on. 
Is there a simple way I can achieve this ?

Comment: I haven't downvoted, but it literally took me 20 seconds to google and find the solution. I suspect that played a part.

Comment: Sure. I see. Its a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ints will always be saved as '1'. If you want to display it as '01' then you can use something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i = 2;
    DecimalFormat twodigits = new DecimalFormat("00");
    System.out.println(twodigits.format(i));
}
```

Output:

```
02
```

Comment: `"00"` would be enough for this.

Comment: @Marcelo: You are correct, I have changed it accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

ints don't have a format. They're numbers. Strings have a format. You can format a number using NumberFormat or DecimalFormat.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I wonder how else could I convey that I want the integers format to be different than what I got.

Answer (score 4):

This is more of a formatting issue.  If the id is a number, the Empolyee.toString() or some similar function can format the id however you want.

```
String.format("%02d", id);
```

Will zero padd the id to 2 places for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Decimal Format

[Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

use String instead of int.

```
String istr = "";
for(int i=01;i<31;i++){
  Employee e = new Employee();
  if( i<10 )
    istr = "0" + i;
  else
    istr = "" + i;

  e.setEmpId(istr);
  aList.add(e);
}
```

of course you will need to have `setEmpId(String s)` method.