# Trying to not Omit Leading 0's when writing from Int to Hex using buffered writer

Tags: java, string, hex, bufferedwriter

I create buffered writer

```
BufferedWriter errorReport = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ErrorReport.txt"));
```

Then I wanted to write while converting my integer to a hex.

```
  errorReport.write(Integer.toHexString(version))
```

This works perfectly, except it omits leading 0's as it writes the minimum possible length.  Say 'version' is a byte in length and simply prints 6.  Well I know the actual value is actually 06.  How do I keep these leading 0's?

I tried errorReport.write(String.format("%03x", Integer.toHexString(version)), but get an error for illegalFormatConversionException x != java.lang.String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` specifies hexadecimal so `format` will perform the conversion by passing the integer directly

```
errorReport.write(String.format("%03x", version));
```

Comment: 0 - to pad with zeros and
3 - to set width to 3 and 'x' for hexadecimal  [refer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/275715/1897935)

Comment: Beautiful.  Yup.  I was like I was converting it twice.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're very close. The JVM is complaining that you are trying to hex-format a string.  Try `errorReport.write(String.format("%03x", version))`

Comment: Beautiful.  Yup.  I was like I was converting it twice.
Thanks