# How to print the integer 00 instead of java printing 0

Tags: java

I have a variable saying `private int minutes = 00`.

If I do `System.out.println(minutes)`, Java will print `0` instead of `00`, which is the value. It is removing the last zero, but in this particular example, I want it to print `00`. How to do that?

I also tried making minutes a string, and do: `Integer.parseInt(minutes)` and then print that. But the result is the same.

Comment: Before you start doing things without knowing that you're doing them, if your `int` literal starts with a `0` it is an Octal.

Comment: This has been asked before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, Java's `Integer.parseInt(String s)` method is identical to calling `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix)` with a radix of 10. `parseInt` with a single argument won't treat the string as an octal number. (That said, prepending an integer _literal_ with 0 will get you octal values.)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
int n = 00;
System.out.printf("%02d%n", n);
```

```
00
```

But be careful with prepending int literals with a `0`, since that makes them [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) (see [JLS §3.10.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)).

For instance,

```
int n = 010;
System.out.printf("%02d%n", n);
```

```
08
```

Comment: So it should be just `int n=0` - consider `n=09`!

Comment: @GyroGearless, Yup! `int n = 09;` would make for an angry compiler.

Answer (score 8):

You can print with a format:

```
System.out.printf("%02d%n", minutes);
```

Explanation:

- The `%02d` specifies an integer conversion (`$d`) with a width of 2 and a 0 padding flag.
- The `%n` specifies a line terminator (to mimic the new line that `println` adds)

If you want to convert `minutes` to a `String` for use within the program (rather than printing) you can use `String.format` to the same effect:

```
int minutes = 0;
String sMinutes = String.format("%02d", minutes);
```

More information can be found in the [docs on `Formatter` syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax).

Answer (score 6):

You can do the following -

```
private int minutes = 0
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("00");
String aFormatString = formatter.format(minutes);

System.out.println(aFormatString);
```

Just saving some lines - `System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00").format(minutes));`

Comment: Thanks all. Now I see another problem for me. What I do is set the time like  time = hour + ":" + minutes. If the time is 11:00, this will set the time to be  11:0. Can I use the formatting here?

Comment: You can pass the hour also in the formatter. Like - String time = formatter.format(hours) + ":" + formatter.format(minutes).

Answer (score 0):

you can try this method, i've learned it in the college

```
private static String formate(int valor) {
    return (valor < 10 ? "0" : "") + valor;
}
```

Comment: 1) It fails for negative numbers.  2) It doesn't scale if you want to multiple leading zeros.  Using `printf` is a much better approach.