# Adding zeros in the number with lower digits

Tags: java

i have a function that generates 2 random numbers and determine the number with the highest number of digits. What i want is to add zeros in the number with lower digits to make them equal. how can i do that? for example
First number: 340
Second Number: 3

i want the result to be 340 and 003.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int lengthOfBigger = String.valueOf(biggerNumber).length();
String pattern = "%0" + lengthOfBigger + "d";

String smallerNumberPadded = String.format(pattern, smallerNumber);
```

Taken mostly from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

EDIT:

For just spaces change pattern to

```
String pattern = "% " + lengthOfBigger + "d";
```

Comment: Added in spaces to the answer @user2419435

Answer (score 1):

you can use `System.out.printf("%03d", valueName);`

what happens is that any value that will be printed would be at least 3 numbers in length and it will print preceding 0s.