# Java Format Long

Tags: java, android

I have Hours, Minutes and Seconds stored in long variables. Pretend that the current values of these are:

```
long seconds = 30;
long minutes = 0
long hours = 0;
```

When I convert these to strings and print them:

```
Long.toString(Hours)+":"+Long.toString(Minutes)+":"+Long.toString(Seconds)
```

The output looks like

0:0:30

I want:

00:00:30

I'm assuming this should be straight forward but I cant work it out..

Comment: `System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds)`. Or `String.format`, or some variant.

Comment: you can find there some exampels: [Adding leading Zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Comment: It's a good manner to mark solutions by clicking on a gray tick under the downvote gray triange next to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
System.out.printf("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

If you want to store the `String` in a variable do the following:

```
String s = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds);
```

Answer (score -1):

use `String.format("%02d", your number)`

for more info read [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)