# How do I pad a negative integer with leading zeroes?

Tags: java, scala

Here is how my method is currently defined in Scala, i've been following [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275715/967713)

```
  def digitFormatter(long: Long, numDigits: Int): String = {
    String.format(s"%0${numDigits}d", long)
  }
```

This seems to work ok with postive integers, i get this expected behavior

```
    assert(digitFormatter(0, 1) == "0")
    assert(digitFormatter(0, 2) == "00")
    assert(digitFormatter(1, 2) == "01")
    assert(digitFormatter(10, 2) == "10")
```

However this doesn't seem to work with negative numbers, this is what I would expect my output to be

```
    assert(
      digitFormatter(-1, 2) == "-01")
```

However the result I get is just `-1`. How do I pad leading zeroes on negative numbers using the java std libraries?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I think that's scala-ese for 'apply variable substitution and other templatey things to this string', and is what makes `${whatsit}` work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no Java format available that does this: They format on total string width, not on number of zeroes. The easiest way is to vary the length of the padding depending on whether the argument is negative:

```
def digitFormatter(long: Long, numDigits: Int): String = {
  val padlength = if (long >= 0) numDigits else numDigits + 1
  String.format(s"%0${padlength}d", long)
}
```

Comment: Compiles for me: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/jsSKh3ZjRUWCWxZqq36R7A -- fixed the off-by-one

Comment: To work around the bug in 2.12, use `String.format(s"%0${padlength}d", Long.box(long))`

Answer (score 2):

You've mischaracterised what String.format does. In your code, you have `${numDigits}` which suggests you think that number in front of the `d` is the number of digits.

No, it's the number of characters.

In other words:

```
String.format("%05d", -12)
```

produces the string `-0012`, because you asked for a string which is at minimum 5 characters long, and which applies 0-padding to get to 5 characters.

If you want a method which turns e.g. `-12` into `-00012` (6 characters, 5 digits) and +12 into `00012` (5 characters, 5 digits), then you'd have to do something like:

```
def digitFormatter(long: Long, numDigits: Int): String = {
    var numChars = numDigits + (if (long < 0) 1 else 0)
    String.format(s"%0${numChars}d", long)
}
```

NB: I'm not a scala programmer, I'm taking a bit of a stab with that ternary operator, but I think you can do that in scala.

Comment: this causes a runtime exception 

>java.util.DuplicateFormatFlagsException: Flags = '0'
 at java.util.Formatter$Flags.parse(Formatter.java:4443)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.flags(Formatter.java:2640)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.<init>(Formatter.java:2709)
 at java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2560)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2501)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2455)
 at java.lang.String.format(String.java:2940)

Comment: I've changed it to `String.format(s"%0${numChars + numDigits}d", long)` but it still doesn't work. 

`"-[]1" did not equal "-[0]1"`

Comment: @Chris use your scala skills, and try to understand the answer. If you ask for a minimum of 5 digits and toss -1 through there, your current code (without these updates) would print `-0001` - surely you can figure it out from there. I've updated the answer with what I think scala's ternary mode is.

Comment: That error indicates my original snippet was resulting in 'numChars' being 0, probably because of operator precedence. All you need is (). As a general tip, with scala, compiler errors are incredibly obtuse so you need to spend a little time trying to figure out what's happening before just giving up, because otherwise, scala isn't for you.

Comment: I don't want to say that scala errors are always perfect, but that error is coming from the Java runtime, not from the scala compiler.

Answer (score 0):

`String.format` should not be used at Scala. You can read the post [The Scala String format approach (and Java String.format)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-string-formatting-java-string-format-method/) by Alvin Alexander.

To make it work in Scala you need to do:

```
def digitFormatter(long: Long, numDigits: Int): String = {
  val padlength = if (long < 0) numDigits + 1 else numDigits
  s"%0${padlength}d".format(long)
}
```

You can find the [format method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.6/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.html#format(args:Any*):String) in Scala docs. Code run can be found at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/QChqB3DqTcSmVMb6a4tiWQ/18).

Answer (score -1):

You can do it just as below:

```
String result = ((value < 0) ? "-" : "") + String.format("%05d", Math.abs(value));
```