# Get day of month from LocalDate with leading zero

Tags: java, java-8, localdate

I get date in a format like `LocalDate dateOfBirthday = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);`.

I need to get the day of the month from that date. I using `dateOfBirthday.getDayOfMonth()` and it works and return `1`, but I need to get `01`.

How I can do it?

Comment: No, I can get date LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 10); and it won't be work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Comment: `1` from `getDayOfMonth()` is an integer, `01` would be a string. So you have to covert it

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS If that answers the question, then it is giving the wrong answer. Given a `LocalDate` we should not convert first to `int` and then to a zero-padded `String`. We have `DateTimeFormatter` for the purpose, which is not mentioned in the question you mention. The duplicate marking is rather harmful.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Benjamin M correctly stated in a comment, `01` would be a string (not an `int`). The correct way to convert a date to a string goes through a formatter. **Edit:** This one gives you a two-digit day of month (01 through 31):

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter dayOfMonthFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd");
```

To use it with your birth date:

```
    LocalDate dateOfBirthday = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
    String twoDigitDayOfMonth = dateOfBirthday.format(dayOfMonthFormatter);
    System.out.println("Day of month: " + twoDigitDayOfMonth);
```

Output is:

> Day of month: 01

**Original answer:** This one gives you a two-digit month — so 01 for January through 12 for December:

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter monthFormatter
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM");
```

To use it with your birth date:

```
    LocalDate dateOfBirthday = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
    String twoDigitMonth = dateOfBirthday.format(monthFormatter);
    System.out.println("Month: " + twoDigitMonth);
```

Output is:

> Month: 01