# How to increment "01" as "02" ,"03"...."10","11" in java?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I have a `x-path` in selenium which contains dynamic value as p01 to p15. If So, if I increment it should pass like 02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09,10,11,12 like this.

But i am unable to find a code to increment a value with 0 prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the complete nature of the request because there is some information missing but you can adding leading zeroes to an integer in java with String format.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String formatted = String.format("%02d", 5);
        String formatted1 = String.format("%02d", 11);
        System.out.println(formatted);
    }
}
```

[Add leading zeroes to number in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275711/add-leading-zeroes-to-number-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple function to do it and then use it in your loop:

```java
public getPathValue(int x)
{
   return x < 10 ? "p0" + x : "p" + x;
}
```

If we call it with value 1 => `getPathValue(1)` as return value we will have `p01`.

If we call it with value 10 or larger => `getPathValue(10)` as return value we will have `p10`.